# Seaborn FacetGrid barplots and hue

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

```
interval    segment  variable        value
4   02:00:00      Night  weekdays   154.866667
5   02:30:00      Night  weekdays   100.666667
6   03:00:00      Night  weekdays    75.400000
7   03:30:00      Night  weekdays    56.533333
8   04:00:00      Night  weekdays    55.000000
9   04:30:00      Night  weekends    53.733333
10  05:00:00      Night  weekends    81.200000
11  05:30:00      Night  weekends   125.933333
14  07:00:00    Morning  weekdays   447.200000
15  07:30:00    Morning  weekends   545.200000
16  08:00:00    Morning  weekends   668.733333
17  08:30:00    Morning  weekends   751.333333
18  09:00:00    Morning  weekdays   793.800000
19  09:30:00    Morning  weekdays   781.125000
23  11:30:00       Noon  weekdays   776.375000
24  12:00:00       Noon  weekdays   741.812500
25  12:30:00       Noon  weekends   723.000000
26  13:00:00       Noon  weekends   734.562500
27  13:30:00       Noon  weekends   763.882353
28  14:00:00  Afternoon  weekdays   810.411765
31  15:30:00  Afternoon  weekdays   855.411765
32  16:00:00  Afternoon  weekdays   824.882353
33  16:30:00  Afternoon  weekends   768.529412
34  17:00:00  Afternoon  weekends   790.812500
35  17:30:00  Afternoon  weekends   809.125000
```

I want to produce a faceted grid of bar plots, one for each variable (weekdays/weekends) and then colour the bars according to the "segment" column.

Producing the two bar plots is very straightforward:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(melted, col="variable")
g.map(sns.barplot,'interval','value')
```

This produces (I know the xlabels are wrong, I can correct that):
[image]

I'm stuck at colouring the bars according to "segment". Per the docs, all I need to do is add the variable when instantiating the FacetGrid and set some palette:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(melted, col="variable",hue="segment",palette="Set3")
g.map(sns.barplot,'interval','value')
```

But this produces:
[image]

The bars are stacked in front of each other instead of being spread across the whole interval. What am I missing here?

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0730b697b6d189905b19) with the dataset.

Comment: You need to pass `hue` in the `map` call, but it is better to use `factorplot`.

Comment: @mwaskom using `factorplot` did the trick, perhaps you wanna add that as an answer

Comment: fyi `factorplot` has been deprecated in favor of [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

Comment: thanks for the pointer @jkr! I added an answer using catplot.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because `interval` is nested within the `x` variable (`segment`), you need to tell `barplot` about all of the possible levels of the `x` variable, so that they are not drawn on top of each other:

```
times = df.interval.unique()
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="variable", hue="segment",
                  palette="Set3", size=4, aspect=2)
g.map(sns.barplot, 'interval', 'value', order=times)
```

[image]

Comment: `size` doesn't exist anymore (using seaborn 0.12.1); use `height` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and went for catplot instead. In your case it should be something like this:

```
sns.catplot(melted, kind="bar", x="interval", y="value", col="variable", hue="segment")
```

Doc: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html